# How to use Java to calculate average from input?

Tags: java, if-statement

I need a program that should add x numbers. The numbers should come from user input so I need some sort of loop. I have gotten as far as shown below, but I'm stuck since I have no idea how to add a new number without deleting the previous?

```
System.out.println("How many numbers to use?");
int number = keyboard.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i<number ; i++) {
    System.out.println("whats the  number");
    double first = keyboard.nextDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int number = keyboard.nextInt();
double sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i<number ; i++) 
{
    System.out.println("whats the  number");
    sum += keyboard.nextDouble();
}

double average = sum / number;
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you need is the average, you don't need to keep all the numbers you get from user input. Just keep one variable that holds their sum.

define the `sum` variable outside the loop (initialized to 0), and add to it each number you get from user input.

Answer (score 0):

public class Average {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double sum = 0;
    int num;
    System.out.println("enter how many num");
    num = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("please enter " + num + " numbers");
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        sum += sc.nextDouble();
    }
    double avg = sum / num;
    System.out.println("Average of " + num + " numbers is:" + avg);
}
```

}